# insert append after form return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i try this code:

```
$("#gerenciarUsuario").submit(function() {
        var cartao = $('#cartao').val().length;
        var cvv = $('#cvv').val().length;
        if(cartao == 0 || cvv == 0) {
            if( !$('#cards').hasClass('wrong')) { 
                    $('#cards').append('<label id="cartaoCvvError" class="error" style="color: #b94a48;">Cartão ou CVV incompletos</label>'); 
                    $('#cards').addClass('wrong');
                }
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    });
```

i'm debuggind with firebug, and the message appears but when return false the msg in append disappears.

basically this is a validation but i need after return false i put one msg in the end of div.

what i need to do?

Comment: A `return` can't make a DOM object disappear. The problem must lie somewhere else. Use a debugger, set breakpoints and trace the code to find where.

Answer (score 0):

Append usually puts content at the end *inside* of a DOM which means it'll try to place your label inside the input. What you probably want to use is .after() http://api.jquery.com/after/